# Has anyone integrated NUnit with Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, nunit

Has anyone integrated NUnit with Visual Studio? I'm trying to set up a build pipeline [like this one](http://machinesareus.blogspot.mx/2012/03/build-pipeline-for-net-apps-using-open.html). But, I'm pretty new to .NET and I'm still understanding how things work. There are many resources in the internet on NUnit + VS, and I'm confused.

Comment: Which edition of Visual Studio 2010 do you have? Express or not?

Comment: I have the "not express" version :)

Comment: Good, because it's not supported to install plug-ins to Express edition.

Answer (score 15):

I'd recommend you to use [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/).
As some say, "It just works".
Disadvantages/side effects of this choice in your case could be:
  1. Resharper is not free;
  2. Running unit-tests is minor part of Resharper - it also includes tons of other features, which you maybe do not need for now(but you can disable most of them in setttings).

Free solution is - [Visual Nunit 2010](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c8164c71-0836-4471-80ce-633383031099) Visual studio extension. Free and does exactly what you want.

---

**UPDATE**
How to add NUnit to your project.
I've found [this tutorial](http://weblogs.asp.net/aghausman/archive/2009/08/08/getting-started-with-unit-testing-in-c.aspx). Follow it step-by-step, I've found it helpful and complete for .NET novices.

The only difference is that in `Running Unit-Tests` section for running tests author uses test runner tool that is distributed within NUnit itself, but you can use ReSharper runner as [described in JetBrains' docs](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/unit_testing.html)

Comment: I NEVER leave home without it.

Comment: If you're uncomfortable with the cost of Resharper, something like TestDriven.net (http://testdriven.net/) is a reasonable alternative for integrating with NUnit

Comment: Although it's not specifically stated in the question, the linked blog posts specifies open source. As awesome as Resharper is, free it is not.

Comment: Are you saying ReSharper has a Testing framework integrated? At the end I'll like to have that running with rake+albacore ( see link ) but I guess the first step is to have it running directly in VS2010

Comment: ReSharper don't has integrated test framework. It has ability to run tests written on couple of unit-testings frameworks(NUnit, MSTest, XUnit(after some tweaking), and maybe smt else). So, you just could write tests with NUnit, and Resharper can run it

Comment: For running NUnit tests via `rake` [albacore NUnitTask](https://github.com/derickbailey/Albacore/wiki/NUnitTask) shoud help, I think.

Comment: awesome, I have resharper indeed. So.. I just have to look on Jetbrains site to findout how to install the plugin. As for albacore, that was my second question ... you read my mind... :) thank a lot

Comment: `have to look on Jetbrains site to findout how to install the plugin.` Like I've said - it just works) launching installer and clicking next->..->next should be enough

Comment: Ok, then I have to look into ... mmhhh NUnit site to install the .. mhhh dll? I guess :-(  :) probably I already have it... feel kind of lost

Comment: @aleksey.berezan I end up in the same place :( How do I integrate NUnit ( now with ) ReSharper? :P

Comment: @aleksey.berezan Yeap, it was pretty easy. Hadn't had the time to update. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

I'm using this:
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c8164c71-0836-4471-80ce-633383031099

Which works quite well for me. You can access it within VS2010 from View->Other Windows->Visual NUnit

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! -- I had already installed this and couldn't figure out how to launch it.

Answer (score 2):

I used TestDriven until it was no longer free, I used Resharper but felt it slowed down my machine too much, I tried the VisualNUnit extension but it appeared to spawn multiple processes of itself that would keep a hold on some of my DLLs, I added NUnit itself as a command under Visual Studio Tools (and also with a toolbar button and some macros in Visual Studio to start the current test and attach) but that cost some effort to set up and didn't feel smooth enough after being spoiled with tools like TestDriven. Eventually I tried **[NCrunch](http://www.ncrunch.net/)**... I am hooked ever since, and I have even started to favor it over TestDriven! the next tool on my "NUnit bucket list" will be the [NUnit extension for Visual Studio 11](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=vsTestAdapter&r=2.6).

PS: NCrunch should work on your Visual Studio 2010 and the homepage has a very decent demo video.

Answer (score 2):

First download and install the NUnit

Step 1: Open Visual studio

Step 2: Open your project

Step 3: Select Properties from Solution Explorer

Step 4: Select Debug option in the properties window

step 5: select 'Start external program' under the section 'Start Action'

Step 6: Select the path of the NUnit file

Step 7: Save it.

After that when you debug your project NUnit will open.

Answer (score 1):

[Setting up Visual C#2010 Express with NUnit](http://joger.net/?p=88)

Comment: +1 Not necessarily integrated into VS, but a passable solution.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2011(BETA) is compatible with 2010 and provides test runners out of the box. Refer to [Visual Studio 11 Beta Unit Testing – What’s New](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=790) and [Visual Studio 11 Beta - Unit Testing Plugins List](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/03/02/visual-studio-11-beta-unit-testing-plugins-list.aspx). For continuous integration (CI) server U can use [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) and also run those test on the server.

Answer (score 1):

The original and still quite ok test runner.

[Test Driven .net](http://testdriven.net/)

Used to be free, but now costs a small fee unless you're a student or open source developer.